# How to set an Odoo docker container using local database?

Tags: docker, odoo, docker-compose

I am trying to set an Odoo docker container that will use a local postgres database. What kind of configuration params should I use in a docker-compose to make that possible?
I could use some help with postgresql commands to create an odoo user, create a database and set a password.

Answer (score 0):

You can use docker-compuser with file like this :

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: odoo:11.0
    ports:
      - "8069:8069"
    environment:
    - HOST=your_host_name_or_ip
    - USER=db_user
    - DB=db_name
    - PASSWORD=password
```

Then run the command:

docker-compose  up -d